# Changing a label, using Query, when it has the form element inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to change the form label below using Jquery but found that changing the HTML removed the form element inside the label. Can anyone show me how I can change the lable text without removing the form element. Thanks!

```
<label for="field_217-0">

    <input id="field_217-0" type="radio" value="Yes" name="item_meta[217]"></input>

     Yes

</label>
```

Lets say I want to change above to 'Yes Sir!'

So far all I have is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("label[for='field_217-0']")
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try `$("label[for='field_217-0']").append(' Sir!');`

Comment: `$('#field_217-0').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue = 'something'` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xxtoseab/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the input and then replace the contents with the input and the new label:

```
var label = $("label[for='field_217-0']");
var input = label.find("input");
label.html(input).append("New Label");
```

...also you don't need the duplicate `.ready()` layers.